# Room above garage cold

Tags: insulation

I have a room over an attached garage which gets much colder than the rest of the rooms. I think there is no insulation in the garage ceiling (I haven’t checked it yet). I saw some suggestions online and some of them mention taking the drywall off and using spray foam. I do not want to go that route since it will be costly option.

What I am thinking of doing is have someone use blown in insulation in the garage ceiling or take down the drywall and put the foam board between the joists, then seal it with spray foam from a can, and then put batt style insulation and put the drywall back and finish it. Is this still a good option?

Comment: Some questions need to be asked and answered first. What's your climate? How much colder does the room get? Is the HVAC system adequate in that room? How's the wall and ceiling insulation? Is the garage heated?

Comment: I live in Chicago. Room gets cold that you can feel it as soon as you open the door. The cold air just hits you. The garage is not heated and yes room does have two heating vent which blows hot air.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Comment: Hi all, thank you for your feedback. I ended up replacing the garage door with new insulated door and that help reducing the heat transfer.

Comment: I 've heard it is very common problem, lot of people have it. Includes me. I checked insulation between garage and room. It is regular. But I guess it may another problem, the duct system not done properly. Ducts run to close to outside wall. Check air temperature in outlets while heating

Comment: Please make your comment into an answer, then click the check mark so people know this has been resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blown insulation may be cheaper and do a good job.
You could use a combination of foam boards and batts if the 2x’s are deep enough. 
How is this room heated? This may be part of the problem also some rooms over the garage were additions and proper heating not installed so this should be part of your investigation.
I mention the heating because if built originally with the house they were normally insulated.

Comment: There are two vents in the room which blows hot air. However garage is not heated.

Comment: How does the ducting to those vents get to the room? If the ductwork is uninsulated and in the uninsulated space in the room floor/garage ceiling, you may get a significant warmth boost just from insulating the ductwork.

Comment: One thing I would like to point out is that sheet rock joints are not finished. They are just screwed to the ceiling and not finished. And as far as duct goes they are covered with sheet rock but I am not sure if they are insulated inside the sheet rock

Comment: Ok taping the joints will help hold the heat in, if the nails or screws were covered taping would not take much time and will make a difference. If screws were used it would not be hard to remove a sheet and see if their is insulation in there.

Comment: Ok thank for the recommendations. I will try and see if there is insulation behind the sheet rock. 

I also read online that temp solution might be to use space heater in the garage. If so what kind of heater is best suited for my situation which I can leave turned on whole night. (This heater idea will be temp fix for my solution)

Comment: I don’t care for space heaters , they usually draw the max allowed and really stress the outlets. I do use some 240v heaters in cargo containers for heat they cost ~110 with shipping from amazon 17000btu by profusion, these heat a 40’ metal cargo container but I am sure the electrical bill jumps when we turn them on.